# What is the take off and landing performance of the MQ-9?

Tags: military, landing, aircraft-performance, takeoff, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

At maximum takeoff weight (listed on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Atomics_MQ-9_Reaper) as 10,494 lb (4,760 kg), 11,700 pounds (5,300 kg) with upgraded landing gear), what is the minimum runway distance required (not including safety margin) for an [MQ-9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Atomics_MQ-9_Reaper?wprov=sfla1) takeoff at sea level on a standard day?

It is also stated (same reference), that the improved landing gear provides a 30% improvement in landing max weight.  What is the landing max weight and the corresponding minimum runway distance (again, without safety margin and on a sea level standard day)?